# How can i get a td by clicking if it has previous td's overflowed text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If a click is made on the second `td` which has overflow text of previous `td`, the handler is returning the first `td` as the text belongs to first `td`. Instead of that i need to select the second `td` irrespective of the overflow text it has.
Thanks in advance.

Play with: https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/

Comment: is it https://jsfiddle.net/sherali/r4naq17z/

Comment: not as expected.When i select second cell in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/), it selects the first cell only as it has first cell's text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think instead of setting the attribute to true all the time you have to set it to false on blur and you need to set the css property `position:relative;` to the `td`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').on({
    click: function() {
      $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true').focus();
    },
    blur: function() {
      $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative; /*<-----add this position in the css*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking on overflowing text here still goes back to the td it's overflowing from rather than the cell you've actually clicked on

Comment: @JamesThorpe `position:relative;` is what actually it needed.

Answer (score 2):

A hackish css only way would be this

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 1;

}
td:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 2;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

and so on...

EDIT: Now I realized the question isn't about css, I'm sorry about that.

Try this one with javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/3/

EDIT 2 : Can someone confirm if this works.

Only css not-hackish solution

https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/4/

Comment: I don't think the question precludes a CSS answer - this _does_ solve the problem

Comment: I just realized that the problem isn't a css one. Should I remove the answer ?

Comment: It's not **not** a CSS problem either.  It's just the way things work.  I think a CSS fix is perfectly acceptable.  I'd question why you'd want your text overflowing like this in the first place, but I don't have a problem with this as an answer to the question asked.

Comment: I wanted to say "The question is not tagged with css tag".

Comment: The "right" answer can always be at a tangent to how the OP was thinking, that's how we learn :)

Comment: This wont be a exact solution as we may have n no. of `td`. We can't provide `z-index` for all `td`s. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Paran0a That also works - as per [Jai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988157/791010), it turns out you only need the `position:relative` - the z-index isn't necessary

Comment: Ok awesome glad we got our answer !