# How can i check whether a td has a overflowed text of some other td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

How to check the fourth `td` has overflowed content of second `td`

I need to get whether the `td` has other `td`'s overflowed text and also which`td`'s text is overflowed on this.

How can i check the `td`for which `td`'s text overflowed it.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/5/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get a td by clicking if it has previous td's overflowed text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988044/how-can-i-get-a-td-by-clicking-if-it-has-previous-tds-overflowed-text)

Comment: @JaromandaX OP older post is clicking the td if there is over flow this one is checking if there is overflow i think they are different

Answer (score 1):

I saw your fiddle and I guess you failed showing overflow as `ellipsis`. It's not a good idea to show overflow text and check if a `td` container other `td`'s content. Try this snippet and write if it solves your problem:

```css
table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   table-layout:fixed;
   width:500px;
}
td{
   border: 2px solid black;
   width:25%;
   height:20px;
   padding:0px;
}
td > div{            /* ADDED */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <div>Second cell text overflow to Third cell</div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Notice:

I added `div` inside `td` cause `text-overflow` won't work for `td` elements.

Comment: he wants to check for over flow not limit the over flow `How to check the third td has overflowed content of second td` checking and limiting are two different things

Comment: yes, they are. But I guess the OP wants to check for an overflow due to inability to constraint the overflow to ellipsis. Who on earth would want table with table items containing content from other tds?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

[The first version](https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/11/) worked for adjacent cells. To collect / find all cells which are possibly affected, I propose a different approach.
Be aware, that this function is limited to cells with an equal size. In case you want to handle different cell sizes, you'll need to modify the calculation of affected cells.

```
$(function(){
    var self, index, affectedCells;
    // loop over all cells...
    $('td').each(function() {
        // test if the cell contains a text too long....
        if(this.scrollWidth > $(this).outerWidth()) {
            // in case the cell has too long text...
            self = $(this);
            self.addClass('has_overflow');

            // get current index
            index = self.closest('tr').find('td').index(self);

            // look how many cells are effected
            affectedCells = Math.ceil(this.scrollWidth / self.outerWidth()) - 1;

            // highlight all effected cells...
            for(var i= 1; i <= affectedCells; i++) {
                 self.closest('tr')
                    .find('td:eq('+(index+ i)+')')
                    .addClass('is_overflown');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

The updated fiddle [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/12/).

Comment: axel i think you should add the class to the next td because the next td has overflow from the td with overflow.

Comment: It is ok for adjacent cells. If the case for 1st and 4th `td` means and also how can i get which `td`'s text is overflowed here.

Comment: @koushikr correct -  I have updated my answer and fiddle one more time.

Comment: It works fine when calculated from second cell(cell with overflow text). But i need to find that second cell has overflow text with respect to fourth cell. I am having fourth cell and i need to check whether some text is overflowed in it and get the cell which has that text.

Comment: @koushikr well all you'll need to do is running the test each time you focus a cell, if your focused cell has the class "is_overflown" you look up the first previous cell with the class "has_overflow" - that's it. Start a bounty in case you'll want a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `white-space:nowrap;` from css

replace with below css for td.

```
td{
border: 2px solid black;
-webkit-user-select:none;
width:25%;
height:20px;
overflow:visible;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
padding:0px;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cssmatter/zvbLz2n3/9/)

let me know if its works!!